# How to create a Linux ELF with only a NOP?

Tags: linux, elf

I am trying to create a simple 64-bit ELF file on Linux without using a compiler, just out of curiosity. For simplicity, I only need it to NOP (0x90).

My current file can be read by "readelf", and its output seems OK. When I execute it, however, I am greeted with a segfault.

The file in question (unformatted so it can be copy-pasted easier):

```
7F 45 4C 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 3E 00 01 00 00 00 78 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 90
```

GDB says segfault at address 0x400079, although the entry point is at 0x400078 and size of the file is 1 byte for the NOP, so why does that non-reserved memory get executed?

Bonus: why do a lot of executables start their code at large virtual addresses, and not at 0x0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you let a compiler handle the low level operations, you can build a *do nothing* program. But if you write it directly in machine code (or even in assembly language), you must handle the gory details, like properly ending the program.

You ask why the non reserved memory is executed. Well, you load something (a NOP code) at 0x400078 and declare that to be the start of program. The loader initializes the memory at 0x400078, loads the instruction pointer with that address, and the processor obediently starts the execution there. It successfully executes the NOP, and as it was not instructed to do anything else, it tries the execute the following instruction at 0x400079. Which segfaults thanks to the memory isolation and the virtual memory manager. In kernel or real mode, it would have executed whatever would be at that memory location with unlimited side effects...

So you must not execute a simple NOP but the system call that tells the OS that the program is ended. According to [exit (system call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_(system_call)) on Wikipedia, it should be on Linux 64 bits:

```
 mov eax, 60  ; sys_exit syscall number: 60
 xor edi, edi ; set exit status to 0 (`xor edi, edi` is equal to `mov edi, 0` )
 syscall      ; call it
```

If your program starts at `mov eax, 60` then it will cleanly exit and even return a 0 status to its caller.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I did not take that into account, I feel silly, I have now successfully created a "does nothing" executable. I am about to step into the super fun world (not) of instruction encoding in order to made my own super simple compiler. I can't imagine the horrors I'll face next year when I plan to make a "Hello World" OS.

Comment: 0x400079 won't segfault. It will only segfault when it gets to 0x401000. Pages are 0x1000 bytes long.

Comment: I love how clear your answer is @SergeBallesta